# div elements positioned to right in css?

Tags: html, css, position, element

im trying to code something in html and css for a coding class in university. I generally have the layout that im looking for, except all my divs are positioned to the right, when i specified for it to be in the center. im seriously stumped on how to fix this.

i will be adding javascript tp this later, but it isn't the issue as of right now. if you need any more information, please let me know.

```css
.body {
  margin: 0;
}


/* HEADER DESIGN */

.header {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  text-align: center;
}

.header p {
  font-size: 8pt;
  color: grey;
}


/* VIDEO DESIGN */

.video {
  text-align: center
}

.meme-approved {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.meme-denied {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 250px;
  left: 0px;
}

.meme-questionable {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 250px;
  left: 0px;
}


/* FILE INSERT DESIGN */

.insert {
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Useless Website</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="description" content="A website that lets you insert a photo/video, and then knuckles from the sonic series approves, denies or questions your work or -meme- ">
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

  <!--contains all HTML-->
  <div class="container">

    <!--text above video-->
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Get your Meme Approved!</h1>
      <h2>By Knuckles himself.</h2>
      <p>An "Introduction to Programming Concepts" coding project by Megan Kingston. Professor is Adam Thomas at Humber College.</p>
    </div>

    <!--video options, under header (technically will be one video)-->
    <div class="video">
      <div class="meme-approved" id="meme-approved">
        <video width="320" height="240" controls>
                        <source src="knuckles-videos/meme-approved.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        <source src="knuckles-videos/meme-approved.mp4" type="video/ogg">
                    </video>
      </div>

      <div class="meme-denied" id="meme-denied">
        <video width="320" height="240" controls>
                        <source src="knuckles-videos/meme-denied.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        <source src="knuckles-videos/meme-denied.mp4" type="video/ogg">
                    </video>

        <div class="meme-questionable" id="meme-questionable">
          <video width="320" height="240" controls>
                            <source src="knuckles-videos/meme-questionable.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                            <source src="knuckles-videos/meme-questionable.mp4" type="video/ogg">
                        </video>
        </div>

        <!--where you insert your meme-->
        <div class="insert">
          <label for="myfile">Place Meme Here:</label>
          <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Which `div` are you referring to? Your HTML was invalid due to not closing two `divs` which I have edited in the snippet. Let us know if that fixed the issue, as everything appears centered in the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on your container

```
.container{
   width:100%;
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

}
```